# ORA-1555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number

Tags: oracle

Any idea about 
ORA-1555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 
I am getting this error and nothing seems to be wrong. Please state under what conditions in may occur and how it can be avoided?

Comment: please let me know - Who has doewnvoted me and why

Comment: -1 for not  adding  about wht you are tring to do

Comment: Of course there could be many more other details for the error (and not the only one mentioned below). What are you trying to do?

Comment: This problem arises very often.I am just tryig to sum up all the conditions which should be taken care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read Tom's answer :
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1441804355350

"The ORA-1555 happens when people try to save space typically.  They'll have small 
rollback segments that could grow if they needed (and will shrink using OPTIMAL).  So, 
they'll start with say 10 or so 1meg rollback segments.  These rollback segments COULD 
grow to 100meg each if we let them (in this example) however, they will NEVER grow unless 
you get a big transaction.
"

Comment: THe link is very useful but I need some more info

Comment: Again, i m only quoting the link :
"What you need to do here is size rollback so 
that it wraps less frequently (less frequently then your long running queries)"

You need more info, but we also need more info from what you are trying to do, and when does it occurs ...

Answer (score 5):

Frequent commits can be the cause of ORA-1555.
It's all about read consistency. The time you start a query oracle records a before image. So the result of your query is not altered by DML that takes place in the mean time (your big transaction). The before image uses the rollback segments to get the values of data that is changed after the before image is taken.
By committing in your big transaction you tell oracle the rollback data of that transaction can be overwritten. 
If your query need data from the rollback segments that is overwritten you get this error. The less you commit the less chance you have that the rollback data you need is overwritten.

One common cause of ORA-1555 is a procedure that does this all in itself : a cursor on a table, loop through the records, and updates/delete the same table and commits every x records.

As guigui told : let the rollback segments grow to contain your whole transaction

Answer (score 2):

Typically this occurs when code commits inside a cursor.

eg.

```
for x in (select ... from ...)
loop
   do something
   commit;
end loop;
```

See the AskTom link form guigui42 though for other examples.

Comment: Commit at the end only. Commiting does not free up resources in oracle in the same way as it does in some other systems because a lock is very lughtweight, and readers and writers do not block each other. Commits more frequently than needed is a common design error when working with Oracle.

Comment: Or you can try the controlled commit. Commit for every 100th row or more.

Comment: It's still inefficient. Why would you commit at all before your transaction was complete?