# sqplus: Retrieve results in chunks (update ROWNUM in loop)

Tags: oracle, select, subquery, sqlplus, rownum

I'm really new to using sqlplus, so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

I have a really long running query of the form:

```
SELECT columnA 
from tableA 
where fieldA in (
  (select unique columnB
  from tableB
  where fieldB in 
    (select columnC
    from tableC
    where fieldC not in
      (select columnD 
      from tableD 
      where x=y 
      and a=b 
      and columnX in 
        (select columnE 
        from tableE
        where p=q)))
  and columnInTableB = <some value> 
  and anotherColumnInTableB = <some other value> 
  and thirdColumnInTableB IN (<set of values>) 
  and fourthColumnInTableB like <some string>);
```

Each of the tables has about 15 - 30 columns and varying number of rows. TableB is the largest, with about 5million rows in all. Tables A - E have between 500,000 - 1 million rows each.

I've tried a couple of approaches:

1) Run this query as is:

This query runs for really long and I get the error -
ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number <> with name <>

I did some research and found things like:
[ORA-1555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686564/ora-1555-snapshot-too-old-rollback-segment-number)

However, I don't have privileges to change the undo segment.

2) I re-wrote the query using with...as, but then I get the error:
unable to extend temp segment by <> in tablespace TEMP

Again, I found explanations as to how to fix this error, but I don't have privileges to extend the temp segment.

The query that takes longest to run is:

```
(select unique columnB
  from tableB  ...
```

The `and fourthColumnInTableB like <some string>);` matches about three million entries in tableB in the worst case.

Someone suggested to me to 'run the query in smaller chunks'.

An approach I thought of was to retrieve data for the long running subquery (

```
(select unique columnB
  from tableB  ...
```

)

in chunks (using ROWNUM as suggested [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:127412348064).
My question is this:

I don't know exactly how many potential matches there are for this subquery. Can I dynamically set ROWNUM to retrieve data in chunks?

If yes, could you please give me an example of what the while loop must look like, and how I can determine when the result set has been exhausted? 
An option I found for this was to check `while @@ROWCOUNT > 0` or use:

```
while exists (query)
```

However, I'm still not sure how to write the loop and how to use a variable (?) to dynamically set ROWNUM.

Basically, I'm wondering if I can do:

```
SELECT columnA 
from tableA 
where fieldA in (
  while all results have not been fetched:
    select * 
    from
      (select a.*, rownum rnum
      from
        (select unique columnB
        from tableB
        where fieldB in 
          (select columnC
          from tableC
          where fieldC not in
            (select columnD 
            from tableD 
            where x=y 
            and a=b 
            and columnX in 
              (select columnE 
              from tableE
              where p=q)))
        and columnInTableB = <some value> 
        and anotherColumnInTableB = <some other value> 
        and thirdColumnInTableB IN (<set of values>) 
        and fourthColumnInTableB like <some string>) a
    where rownumm <= i) and rnum >= i);
    update value of i here (?) so that the loop can repeat
```

How can I update the value of 'i' for rownum/rnum above dynamically in some loop to retrieve results in chunks (of, say, 10000) until the result set has been exhausted?

Also, what should the while loop look like?

I also have no idea how to rewrite this using joins (my knowledge of sql is very limited), so if someone can help me rewrite this more efficiently using joins or any other method, that would work too.

I'd really appreciate any help on this. I've been stuck on this for a few days now and I'm unable to determine a proper solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Why have you tagged mysql and sql-server if your question is about oracle?

Comment: Without details of the tables, data volums, your query and its execution plan I don't think we can help much - it's far too general. Using joins rather than subqueries, and checking your stats are up to date, is the only general advice that jumps out; we can't tell why the way you did that was a problem. Maybe you used old syntax and missed a join condition. You also seem to be trying to follow advice for another RDBMS - focus your research on things that specifically apply to Oracle.

Comment: If the sub-query is the long running bit then you can try using `EXISTS` rather than `IN`. From the [Oracle 10.2 SQL Tuning documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/sql_1016.htm#g42927): *“If the selective predicate is in the subquery, then use IN. If the selective predicate is in the parent query, then use EXISTS.”*

Comment: I edited it to add more details about the tables and general query structure. Hope this helps.

Comment: can you send plan please? 

set linesize 180
set autotrace traceonly 
< Your SQL here>

Answer (score 0):

1) Try removing UNIQUE /DISTINCT clause. It should in-memory sort and temp segment.

2) Try applying a 'rownum < x_rows' filter, in the end, to restrict no of rows to the client and reduce IO.

```
SELECT columnA
FROM tableA
WHERE fieldA IN (
  (SELECT **UNIQUE** columnB
  FROM tableB
  WHERE fieldB IN
    (SELECT columnC
    FROM tableC
    WHERE fieldC NOT IN
      (SELECT columnD
      FROM tableD
      WHERE x      =y
      AND a        =b
      AND columnX IN
        (SELECT columnE FROM tableE WHERE p=q
        )
      )
    )
  AND columnInTableB            = <SOME value>
  AND anotherColumnInTableB     = <SOME other value>
  AND thirdColumnInTableB      IN (<
    SET OF VALUES               >)
  AND fourthColumnInTableB LIKE <SOME string>
  )
  **ROWNUM < 50** ;
```